# How to get quota details of sky drive in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, onedrive

I am developing a Sky drive application for windows phone.i want to know the quota details like total space, free space and used space.i am using wp8 sdk,Visual Studio 2012,live SDK v5.5.i dont want to use 3rd party api.can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Get info:
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Getting_user_information_with_the_Live_Connect_API_for_Windows_Phone

Helper to work with:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668051/Windows-Phone-8-A-Simple-Helper

Comment: https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/tree/master/src/WP8/Samples  a bunch of all possible examples